# Display differences between iPad 1 and iPad 2

Tags: ipad, resolution

When you're trying to develop and iPad game what will be the differences between iPad 1 resources and iPad 2? Seen some example but what's the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The displays are the same. Meaning that you'll have 1024x768 pixels on both models. So you can use the same assets on both devices. The iPad2 has a better CPU, GPU and more memory, so you can technically build more complex applications and load more resources into memory.

You can compare the [exact specs on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices#iPad).

Comment: Then for iPad 2 version I'll have some high-quality pictures, right?

Comment: No, you'll have the same pictures as for iPad 1. The iPad 2 doesn't have a "retina-display"... there are speculations, that such a high-res display will be available in the next generation of iPads (doubling the current resolution).

Comment: I think you should use the same quality for both. It is only if you're working with image manipulation or some other CPU/GPU intensive task that you should consider the differences.

Comment: @bummzack: I thought that there are differences between also for the iPad version; now I've got it... only for iPhone 3 vs iPhone 4.
Thanks!